# Angular 9: How to prevent reload page when change params

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I used angular9 and PathLocationStrategy

> {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy},

My issue is:
When I use form.submit() post data to the backend, and the backend will redirect to the current URL with some params (eg: '/contacts?data=new').
And my website will be reloaded.
I don't want to reload page. I used the params subscribe, but not work

> this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
> this.urlParams = params;
> });

How can I prevent reload the page in this case?

**Update code**

HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="submitForm" novalidate [id]="submitFormId" method="post" isolate-form>
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="Reference" [value]="data.reference">
    <input type="hidden" name="Action" [value]="data.action">
    <button class="btn" (click)="save()">Save</button>
</form>
```

TS:

```
public save() {
        let $form = $('#submitFormId');
        $form.attr('action', this.data.crnUrl);
        $form.submit();
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the HTML form? and the submit method?

Comment: Use router navigation with the updated query params. This will not reload the page.

Comment: @TwoHorses, I updated may question with html and ts code

Comment: @Faisal, I call backend, and the backend will make the redirect url, I cannot navigate router

Comment: because you use the native form submit, the browser will reload the page. You need to handle the form submit yourself with ```(ngSubmit)``` (and remove the ```method="post"```  attribute)

Comment: It means I will use HTTPClient, post request with url = this.data.crnUrl, and body is data of all hidden input. Then waiting for the backend response the redirectUrl, use to navigate. My understand is right?

Answer (score -1):

Because you are using the native form submit, the browser will reload the page. You need to handle form submit within angular to prevent that behavior.

```
  <form [formGroup]="submitForm" novalidate [id]="submitFormId" isolate-form (ngSubmit)="save()">
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="Reference" [value]="data.reference">
    <input type="hidden" name="Action" [value]="data.action">
    <button class="btn" type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Then in your component send the request yourself using `HttpClient`

```
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  public save() {
        let body = {}
        // Get form fields here using FormGroup, and put them into body
        this.http.post(this.data.crnUrl, body)
    }
```

Also, don't use JQuery with angular, because `$form.submit()` is what causing your page to reload.

Comment: This is wrong answer. Could you please explain?

Comment: yes, I added in appModule and childModule

Comment: I added an explanation, this solution solved my exact problem. If it doesn't help, can you edit your question and add the HTML form and the submit method?